# Use locale not included in Craft

Tags: localization, craft2

I have to develop a website under Craft CMS 2 and going to Locale Options I see I can add a language, but I need to use a language that is not included in the official codes for the representation of names of languages.

There's a cultural and important question here for my client, because Valencian language is included into Catalan language under the code "ca_ES" but is frowned upon here. So, I want to use other code, for example, "va_ES". How can I do this under Craft CMS 2?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be ok to just copy the ca_ES file and rename it to whatever handle you like. Full instructions here: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/adding-additional-locales-in-craft-2#creating-custom-locales

I had to do this myself for an Icelandic locale and it worked fine.

Comment: I did it this way, but then the locale name appears as "va_es". Where can I edit this language name?

Comment: Ah yes, I remember this too... to change the name, you'll need to go into each of the locale files that you're using and add it as a new key in the `language` array.

Comment: it works, thanks!